# gspread AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'insert_rows'

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I'm trying to use gspread to insert rows into a Google Spreadsheet

```
self.client = gspread.authorize(creds)
ss = self.client.open_by_key(key)
sheet = ss.worksheet("total")
sheet.insert_rows([["test"], ["test"]], 2)
```

I'm getting the error:
`AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'insert_rows'`

Does anyone know what the issue might be? The weird thing is that I tried using the function `insert_row` which works fine, but am just running into this issue with `insert_rows`

Comment: I thought that from the error message, you might be using older version of gspread. Because it seems that `Worksheet.insert_rows()` was added at v3.6.0. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/releases/tag/v3.6.0) So for example, how about updating gspread to the latest version? But if this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks, that worked for me!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using an older version of gspread and had to update it to v3.6.0 to be able to use `Worksheet.insert_rows()`